# Regex priority of match (forward and rear looking regex)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a monster regex at the moment, and am currently looking at how this best functions.

My regex is listed below and I am curious if there is a way to prioritize the regex in one function rather than just look for a specific match whereever it may exist.

Example:

If in my string i have a match for `([\d]+/[\d]+)` or `([\d]+ / [\d]+)` it would pick that first.

If this match above does not exist then but these existed `([\d]+-[\d]+)` or `([\d]+ - [\d]+)` it would pick that match

After that if `([\d]+)` then it would pick that match as the end marker. If none of those existed it would then just move on to any of the other matches.

So my question is:

**With Regex is there any way to prioritize which match to take first?**

example: Some of my address strings are in the format of `1 - 12 example street`, 
often the regex will pull `12 example street` rather than taking `1 - 12 example street`.

Thanks!

The full regex is listed below:

```
New Regex("( ([\d]+) | ([\d]+-[\d]+) | ([\d]+ - [\d]+) | CAR
SMOULDERING | GAS BOTTLE EXPLOSION | INPUT | OFF | OPPOSITE | CNR |
SPARKING | INCIC1 | INCIC3 | STRUC1 | STRUC3 | G&SC1 | G&SC3 | ALARC1 | 
ALARC3 | NOSTC1| NOSTC3 | RESCC1 | RESCC3 | HIARC1 | HIARC3 | CAR
ACCIDENT - POSS PERSON TRAPPED | EXPLOSIONS HEARD | WASHAWAY AS A
RESULT OF ACCIDENT | ENTRANCE | ENT |FIRE| LHS | RHS | POWER LINES
ARCING AND SPARKING | SMOKE ISSUING FROM FAN | CAR FIRE | FIRE ALARM
OPERATING | GAS LEAK | GAS PIPE | NOW OUT | ACCIDENT | SMOKING | ROOF | 
GAS | REQUIRED | FIRE | LOCKED IN CAR | SMOKE RISING | SINGLE CAR
ACCIDENT | ACCIDENT | FIRE)(.*?)(?=\SVSE| M | SVC | SVSW | SVNE | SVNW
)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

Comment: Your three last posts are unreadable. Please could you take the time to format them correctly (using SO markers, short sentences, newlines, commas, periods). This will increase your chances to have answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have hopefully made it a little easier to read.

Comment: It's really better. Can you write several examples of strings you need to match, I am not sure that you must put all in an alternation, and that you need to use the `RightToLeft` option.

Comment: By examples I assume you mean examples of the strings I am trying to match?

Comment: I added some examples into the main question / discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the 3 first:

```
(\d+-\d+) | (\d+ - \d+) | (\d+ )
```

instead of:

```
([\d]+) | ([\d]+-[\d]+) | ([\d]+ - [\d]+)
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was after, so the priority of the regex match is just left to right, so using the above it should take 25 / 1 example st first, then 12-56 example st (with or without space), then just a strait digit.

Comment: How does this work in multiple regex matches, I have the following regex, which I would have thought CNR, or matches digits first then finally matching GAS PIPE LEAK, however in this case it does not. Instead it matches GAS PIPE LEAK before CNR or Numbers  '(CNR|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )|(?<=GAS PIPE LEAK).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )'

Comment: @user1829564: It should match `CNR` before. Could you update your question with some examples you want to match and the expected results?

Comment: Must have just been a bug with the regex tester I was using, as when i use the http://regexhero.net/tester/ site it works fine.  -- Thanks!